# socket.io emit to all sockets not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, twitter

I have the following code:

```
/* WEB SERVER AND SOCKET */
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3010;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));


io.configure(function () {
  io.set("transports", [
    'websocket'
    , 'xhr-polling'
    , 'flashsocket'
    , 'htmlfile'
    , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
});

/* TWITTER STUFF */

t.track('hashtag');
t.track('sometag');

t.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
    console.log('Tweet received from ' + tweet.user.name + ' (@' + tweet.user.screen_name + '): ' + tweet.text);
    io.sockets.emit('tweet', {
        user: {
            name: tweet.user.name,
            screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name,
            profile_pic: tweet.user.profile_image_url
        },
        text: tweet.text,
        time: tweet.created_at,
        photo: tweet.media.media_url
    });
});
```

When running this, if I tweet using the hashtag, I get the log but no socket message is sent. Also, any following tweets do not do anything, suggesting that the emit function is hanging. In my log when starting the server, at the beginning I see:

```
info  - socket.io started
info  - FlashPolicyFileServer received an error event: listen EADDRINUSE
```

However, connections can still be made. Running `netstat -tulpn | grep :3010` doesn't return anything, so I don't really get what the issue is. I'm running socket.io 0.9.16 and express 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3010;
```

to

```
var port =8080; // for testing
```

Comment: the reason you see the console.log output is simple it is from var t listener. The io.sockets are not up maybe (that's the reason you get no netstat for that port)